# Wi-fi driver and decvice enabled, but no networks found

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

I have been running Ubuntu 20.04 for a few months now, and it has been smooth sailing except for this issue. I have run into it once before and it seemed to go away on its own, but not this time. I started by following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide) guide.

Update: This problem also shows up on my Windows installation. Fast Boot was enabled on Windows, and after turning that off, shutting down, and switching off the power supply the issue has resolved itself on both installations. I will post any updates in the comments.

using

```
nmcli
```

results in

```
wlo1: disconnected
    "Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM4360"
    wifi (wl), 98:48:27:C5:54:D3, hw, mtu 1500
```

I can clearly see that the device is enabled with the command

```
lshw -C network
```

which yields:

```
description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:21:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 03
   serial: 98:48:27:c5:54:d3
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:25 memory:fc400000-fc407fff memory:fc200000-fc3fffff
```

the command

```
lsmod
```

shows that the wl driver is enabled, and using

```
modprobe
```

to disable that driver does cause the system to stop using the device completely (cannot find wi-fi settings in the GUI)

and when I do

```
sudo iwlist scan
```

I get this:

```
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp34s0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlo1      No scan results

usb0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

wlo1 is the wireless adapter.

Finally,

```
sudo iwconfig
```

gives me this:

```
wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
```

I have tried updating and upgrading multiple times and have restarted several times during this process. I have also tried re-installing the driver multiple times in different ways and have not had any success (I made sure to clean up, and the terminal output was all after I tried to fix it). Right now I am on the same OS and using a USB tether to my phone, which is working fine.

As far as I can tell, Ubuntu thinks everything is working fine.

OK, this is that `dkms status` shows:

```
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.13.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.60.02, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.60.02, 5.13.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Running `dpkg -l *broadcom*` shows:

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching *broadcom*
```

And `dpkg -l *bcm*`:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                Version                             Architecture Description
+++-===================-===================================-============-================================================
ii  bcmwl-kernel-source 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.3 amd64        Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source
un  bcmwl-modaliases    <none>                              <none>       (no description available)
un  libcmis-0.5-5       <none>                              <none>       (no description available)
ii  libcmis-0.5-5v5     0.5.2-1ubuntu1                      amd64        CMIS protocol client library
```

`sudo ubuntu-drivers list` output:

```
WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-510-server: package has invalid Support PBheader, cannot determine support level
WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-510: package has invalid Support PBheader, cannot determine support level
nvidia-driver-470-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-470-server-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-510-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-510-server-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-470, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-510, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-510-generic-hwe-20.04)
bcmwl-kernel-source
```

`rkill` output:

```
ID TYPE DEVICE        SOFT      HARD
 2 wlan phy0     unblocked unblocked
 3 wlan brcmwl-0 unblocked unblocked
```

`sudo dmesg | grep -i wlo` output:

```
[    5.575425] wl 0000:21:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[ 1707.631921] wlo1 Scan_results error (-22)
[ 2965.838613] wl 0000:21:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

`sudo dmesg | grep -i networkmanager` does not have any output at all.

`iwlist freq` output:

```
lo        no frequency information.

enp34s0   no frequency information.

wlo1      32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 32 : 5.16 GHz
          Channel 34 : 5.17 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 50 : 5.25 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 54 : 5.27 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 58 : 5.29 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 62 : 5.31 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 66 : 5.33 GHz
usb0      no frequency information.
```

Normally there are about 10 networks available in my location. I normally use one.

`sudo iwlist wlo1 scan | grep -i ssid` output:

```
wlo1      Interface doesn't support scanning : Device or resource busy
```

I will restart and post the different output if there is any

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135906/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-mandrona-wi-fi-driver-and-decvice-enabled-but).